# pig hcatalog error in loading main class

Tags: apache-pig, hcatalog

When I executed 
`$ pig -x local -useHCatalog`. I got the below error. What could be the root cause.

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   .home.hduser.durgasoft.apache-hive-0.13.1-bin.lib.jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:.home.hduser.durgasoft.apache-hive-0.13.1-bin.lib.slf4j-api-2.0.99.jar:.home.hduser.durgasoft.apache-hive-0.13.1-bin.lib.hive-hbase-handler-0.13.1.jar:.home.hduser.durgasoft.apache-hive-0.13.1-bin.hcatalog.share.hcatalog.hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.1.jar:.home.hduser.durgasoft.apache-hive-0.13.1-bin.hcatalog.share.hcatalog.storage-handlers.hbase.lib.*:.home.hduser.durgasoft.apache-hive-0.13.1-bin.hcatalog.share.hcatalog.hive-hcatalog-pig-adapter-0.13.1.jar

What is the root cause.

Comment: hcatalog jars are missing. add them in classpath

Comment: i have added the jars in .bashrc HADOOP_CLASSPATH and PIG_CLASSPATH and refreshed bashrc. But i am getting the errors again.